# Finding the scores for each tweet with a BERT-based sentiment analysis model

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am doing a sentiment analysis of twitter posts and I have a question regarding “German Sentiment Classification with Bert”:

I would like to display the sentiment score (positive, negative, neutral) for each tweet like it is shown on the models card on [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/oliverguhr/german-sentiment-bert)(screenshot)
I tried to go through the implementation of the mode by stepping into every line of code but could not figure out how to find the scores.

[image]

My code is based on the following code:

```
model = SentimentModel()

texts = [
    "Mit keinem guten Ergebniss","Das ist gar nicht mal so gut",
    "Total awesome!","nicht so schlecht wie erwartet",
    "Der Test verlief positiv.","Sie fährt ein grünes Auto."]
       
result = model.predict_sentiment(texts)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can inherit from the model's class and define a function to output the scores:

```
from typing import List
import torch
from germansentiment import SentimentModel


class SentimentModel(SentimentModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def predict_sentiment_proba(self, texts: List[str])-> List[str]:
        texts = [self.clean_text(text) for text in texts]
        # Add special tokens takes care of adding [CLS], [SEP], <s>... tokens in the right way for each model.
        # truncation=True limits number of tokens to model's limitations (512)
        encoded = self.tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(texts, padding=True, add_special_tokens=True,truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
        
        encoded = encoded.to(self.device)
        with torch.no_grad():
                logits = self.model(**encoded)
        
        #label_ids = torch.argmax(logits[0], axis=1)
        return torch.nn.Softmax(dim=1)(logits[0]), self.model.config.id2label
   
texts = ["Mit keinem guten Ergebniss","Das ist gar nicht mal so gut",
    "Total awesome!","nicht so schlecht wie erwartet",
    "Der Test verlief positiv.","Sie fährt ein grünes Auto."]

model = SentimentModel()
scores, ids = model.predict_sentiment_proba(texts)

scores
>tensor([[1.1602e-03, 9.9877e-01, 6.8676e-05],
        [8.8440e-04, 9.9909e-01, 2.3437e-05],
        [9.8738e-01, 1.2542e-02, 7.6997e-05],
        [9.7940e-01, 2.0516e-02, 8.2444e-05],
        [4.1755e-04, 4.6088e-04, 9.9912e-01],
        [2.1236e-05, 5.3932e-05, 9.9992e-01]])
ids
>{0: 'positive', 1: 'negative', 2: 'neutral'}

scores.argmax(dim=-1)
>tensor([1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2]) #negative, negative, positive, positive, neutral, neutral
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also load [this model](https://huggingface.co/oliverguhr/german-sentiment-bert) with huggingfaces [TextClassificationPipeline](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline) directly and get the expected output:

```py
from transformers import pipeline, AutoModelForTokenClassification, AutoTokenizer


ger_senti= pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model='oliverguhr/german-sentiment-bert', tokenizer='oliverguhr/german-sentiment-bert', top_k=3)

texts = [
    "Mit keinem guten Ergebniss","Das ist gar nicht mal so gut",
    "Total awesome!","nicht so schlecht wie erwartet",
    "Der Test verlief positiv.","Sie fährt ein grünes Auto."]

print(ger_senti(texts))
```

Output:

```
[[{'label': 'negative', 'score': 0.9975766539573669},
  {'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.002348615089431405},
  {'label': 'neutral', 'score': 7.477447798009962e-05}],
 [{'label': 'negative', 'score': 0.9989897608757019},
  {'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.0009901983430609107},
  {'label': 'neutral', 'score': 1.9994889953522943e-05}],
 [{'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.9883987307548523},
  {'label': 'negative', 'score': 0.011490345932543278},
  {'label': 'neutral', 'score': 0.00011099433322669938}],
 [{'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.9794018268585205},
  {'label': 'negative', 'score': 0.020515765994787216},
  {'label': 'neutral', 'score': 8.244431955972686e-05}],
 [{'label': 'neutral', 'score': 0.9982169270515442},
  {'label': 'negative', 'score': 0.0012244582176208496},
  {'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.0005586450570262969}],
 [{'label': 'neutral', 'score': 0.9987679123878479},
  {'label': 'negative', 'score': 0.000912801013328135},
  {'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.0003192462318111211}]]
```

Comment: Thank you  for your contribution. Im having speed issues with the implementation with the Inheritance of the models class do you think this approach will be faster?

Comment: Hard to tell without checking the whole code of germansentiment. As far as I can see the only major difference is the [cleanup step](https://github.com/oliverguhr/german-sentiment-lib/blob/29aa0643a45e7e42fbcb1c0e3efc1cfc772862a5/germansentiment/sentimentmodel.py#L40), but I do not expect this to have such a big impact. Can you compare the two approaches alone without your other code? Maybe your bottleneck is somewhere else?

Comment: In some cases, espcially with "neutral" texts the usage of the "TextClassificationPipeline" leads to errors, due to the missing preprocessing. Thats the reason why I created the library.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback. I added the class probabilities feature to the library. You can get the probabilities by just adding the "output_probabilities" parameter:

```
from germansentiment import SentimentModel

model = SentimentModel()

classes, probabilities = model.predict_sentiment(["das ist super"], output_probabilities = True) 
print(classes, probabilities)
```

This gives you the classes as well as the scores

```
['positive'] [[['positive', 0.9761366844177246], ['negative', 0.023540444672107697], ['neutral', 0.00032294404809363186]]]
```